# Turn your android device to a wireless set?

Tags: wi-fi, audio

I would like to know whether there is any app to share audio from an android device to a pc as well as to other android devices connected to the same WLAN network. So that people can communicate to others like using a wireless set without using any mobile network. I know there will be a limit for the range of this setup, but it's not a problem.
Also, I never mind installing any software for this purpose in the pc.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know what do you mean by 'share audio'? Is it *sharing music Files* or *streaming music*. If it is about sharing Music Files, you may use **Xender** from PlayStore which can send files over WiFi to any other user having Xender installed. For PC, you may use **AirDroid** from PlayStore to access any file or separately any Music File from any Browser on PC over Wifi.

If Streaming is your goal, I suggest running a HTTP or FTP server on your android device. You can select the app that suits you from [here.](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=icecoldapps)

Comment: Links: [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en) and [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en).